# What are those java threads starting with "pool"?

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-dump

I have a problem with a Tomcat server that is unable to shutdown gracefully. I have taken a thread dump after I issued the shutdown command, and it looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/7SW4wZN9

The thread which I believe is the "suspect" that does not allow the VM to shut down is the one named "pool-4-thread-1". The rest of them are either daemon threads or internal VM threads. While trying to find out what this thread is for, I noticed that there are other java programs out there that create threads with similar names (For example, JVisualVM creates such threads).

So I'm wondering if someone else knows what this thread is and how it can be created.

Comment: what does it mean "unable to shudtown gracefully" ?

Comment: It means that the VM does not terminate after I run shutdown.sh. It needs a kill signal on the OS level.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These threads are probably created by an ExecutorService that you created in your code somewhere (directly or indirectly through a library) and that needs to be shutdown (for example in a ServletContextListener).

Comment: You are correct, I have created a test class with an ExecutorService and a Thread with this name was created. Any ideas on how I can... hunt this ExecutorService down and kill it?

Comment: Difficult, since they are using the default name, which does not give it away. You could make stack trace dumps while the app is running, maybe you can catch one of them doing actual work. That should give away some class names. What kind of libraries are you using? Anything that might work with background threads?

Comment: Oh, we are using loads and loads of stuff: connection pools, background tasks running in threads, RMI connections, you name it. So it is quite difficult to isolate what causes it. But thanks for the idea, I will generate thread dumps periodically hopping that I can catch the thread doing some actual work.

Comment: Create your `ExecutorService`s with custom 'ThreadFactory`es which set names for your pool threads.

Comment: @palacsint: Yes, that is what should be done. But no one seems to be doing that (and in this case, it is probably a library creating the ExecutorService). And it would be nice if there was an API to set the thread name prefix without the need for a custom ThreadFactory class.

Comment: @Thilo, I realize that this thread is almost 6 years old but even then Google's Guava library allowed to set the name using `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder` like so: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, new ThreadFactoryBuilder()           .setNameFormat("thread-name-%d").build())`